# crystal report formula to check character structure matches

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to see if there is a formula that can check a certain character structure is being used in a string field type 
I need to check if it matches and to use to turn red if it does not match.

ALPHA ALPAH NUM NUM NUM ALPHA

AA123A - ok,
A1234A - Turn red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this as a conditional formatting formula:

```
local stringvar somefield:={table.string_field};

if len(somefield)=7
    and ascw(somefield[1]) in [65 to 90]
    and ascw(somefield[2]) in [65 to 90] 
    and isnumeric(somefield[3 to 5])
    and ascw(somefield[6]) in [65 to 90] then crBlack else crRed
```

Obviously this only works for upper-case alphabetic characters (ASCII values 65-90) as-is, but can easily be changed to accommodate whatever you need.